# How to compile zlib into a DLL on Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, zlib

I have a hard time trying to do something I think is really simple (I must not be the first one to want to do that). I use Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7 to do some C code, and I need inflate/deflate for zip.

I search a little, and I found [zlib](https://zlib.net/). It seem to be exactly what I search: free, cool copyright, no patent and extensively used and tested in other project.

So, I start to download the latest version ([zip of 1.2.11](https://zlib.net/zlib1211.zip)) and here I go, trying to "simply" get the DLL.

However, the documentation state that in order to compile "zlib1.dll", I have to use "./contrib/vstudio/vc..", with ".." the right Visual Studio. But I have Visual Studio 2017 and there are only "vc9" to "vc14", "vc14" being Visual Studio 2015.

The doc say that I have to use Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, and indeed, when I force open with vs2017, I have integrity error.

So I try to install MVC++ 2015, but then it say that I can't install it because I already have something (VS2017) installed.

Is there really no way to achieve something so basic, or there is knowledge that I don't know?

Comment: The easiest way to consume zlib for Windows is just use a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=zlib). I personally use [x86](https://www.nuget.org/packages/zlib-msvc14-x86/) or [x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/zlib-msvc14-x64/) which are compatible with both VS 2015 Update 3 and VS 2017.and use a static library instead of a DLL.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks ! It seem to have worked for me. If you put your comment into a answer, I will gladly upvote & accept it. So long short story : what I want to do is not trivial at all and using a tierce party is the easiest way. I can't believe it ... There is surely something that my ignorance keep me from understanting that something as basic should be simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open source projects can be a challenge to build as their support tends to lag well behind the latest versions of Visual Studio. This is one reason why Visual Studio now supports [cmake](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/) directly.

That said, the easiest way to build zlib for Windows is just use a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=zlib). I personally use [zlib-msvc14-x86](https://www.nuget.org/packages/zlib-msvc14-x86/) or [zlib-msvc14-x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/zlib-msvc14-x64/) which are [binary compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017) with VS 2015 Update 3, VS 2017, and VS 2019. They also provide a static library instead of a DLL.